# How do we separate values fetched from findvalues of XML::LibXMl by a delimiter?

Tags: perl

I have got an XML to parse. Though I am able to fetch them, I cant separate them by a delimiter for further processing. Please advise. My Code is as follows

```
use XML::LibXML;

my $filename = 'Test.xml';

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $dom = $parser->parse_file($filename);
my $root = $dom->documentElement();
my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($root);

foreach my $id ($xpc->findnodes('/dataset/chapter'))
{
    print $xpc->findvalue('mono/route-list', $id);
    print join ",", $xpc->findvalue('mono/route-list', $id);
}
```

For both "print" statements I am getting the same result though the expected ones are :

ophthalmic oral topical nasal injection oral oral oral oral

ophthalmic, oral, topical, nasal, injection, oral, oral, oral, oral

The xml file structure is as below :

```
<dataset id="5"><title>NDC 11</title>
<chapter id="9"><title>NDC 11</title>
<mono id="310694" mid="145787">
<nam>00173074200</nam>
<route-list>
    <list-set-field dbId="25413">
        <name>ophthalmic</name>
    </list-set-field>
</route-list>   
</mono>
<mono id="4128683" mid="536890">
<nam>51079020406</nam>
<route-list>
    <list-set-field dbId="25413">
        <name>oral</name>
    </list-set-field>
</route-list>
</mono>
<mono id="4128743" mid="536930">
<nam>65862007360</nam>
<route-list>
    <list-set-field dbId="25413">
        <name>topical</name>
    </list-set-field></route-list>
</mono>
<mono id="3419599" mid="469070">
<nam>49702021718</nam>
<route-list>
    <list-set-field dbId="25413">
        <name>nasal</name>
    </list-set-field>
</route-list>
</mono>
<mono id="2990346" mid="440470">
<nam>49702022118</nam>
<route-list>
    <list-set-field dbId="25413">
        <name>injection</name>
    </list-set-field>
</route-list>
</mono>
<mono id="2990347" mid="440470">
<nam>49702022144</nam>
<route-list>
    <list-set-field dbId="25413">
        <name>oral</name>
    </list-set-field>
</route-list>
</mono>
<mono id="2990357" mid="440491">
<nam>49702022248</nam>
<route-list>
    <list-set-field dbId="25413">
        <name>oral</name>
    </list-set-field>
</route-list>
</mono>
<mono id="3808911" mid="513570">
<nam>00378410591</nam>
<route-list>
    <list-set-field dbId="25413">
        <name>oral</name>
    </list-set-field>
</route-list>
</mono>
<mono id="4128724" mid="536910">
<nam>60505358306</nam>
<route-list>
    <list-set-field dbId="25413">
        <name>oral</name>
    </list-set-field>
</route-list>
</mono>
</chapter>
</dataset>
```

Comment: Looks like you're not getting back a list, but a string.

Comment: @JimDavis, Hi Jim. what should be the fix to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try this code(note the last line in the for loop):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.016;
use XML::LibXML;

my $filename = 'Test.xml';

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(
    location => $filename,
);

my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($dom);

CHAPTER:
for my $chapter ($xpc->findnodes('/dataset/chapter')) {
    my $string = $xpc->findvalue('mono/route-list', $chapter);
    print $string;

    last CHAPTER;  #<*****NOTE THIS
}
```

You will get the output:

```
          ophthalmic



      oral



          topical



       nasal



       injection



       oral



       oral



       oral



       oral
```

The docs say:

> **findvalue()**
>
> ...returns the literal value of the results.

*results* is more than *one* result.  And *one* result is *all* the *text* between a matching tag.

The xml has a hidden character at the end of each line:

```
  <route-list>\n
    <list-set-field dbId="25413">\n
        <name>ophthalmic</name>\n
    </list-set-field>\n
  </route-list>\n
```

...as well as several spaces/tabs at the beginning of each line.  The spaces/tabs and newlines are considered text, and they are between a `<route_list>` tag.  As a result, the text for *one* result contains all the spaces/tabs/newlines as well.

And findvalue() returns the text from all the results as one string.  You *could* split that string up with a regex to get the individual values; but rather than create more work for yourself, you can do this:

```
CHAPTER:
for my $chapter ($xpc->findnodes('/dataset/chapter')) {
    for my $name ($xpc->findnodes('//mono/route-list//name', $chapter)) {
        say $name->textContent;
        last CHAPTER;
    }
}

--output:--
ophthalmic
```

...or even this:

```
CHAPTER:
for my $chapter ($xpc->findnodes('/dataset/chapter')) {
    for my $name_text ($xpc->findnodes('//mono/route-list//name/text()', $chapter)) {
        say $name_text;
        last CHAPTER;
    }
}
```